# How to store Infopath form attachments in document library?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

In Infopath form the attachments gets embeded within the file as bas64 string and in my case i may have multiple attachments (up to 6-7 attachments). Keeping attachments as part of the Infopath form itself will make my form size huge as well wont allow me to add some business rules on individual attachments.

Is there a way i can store these attachments in a separate document librarya and then should have a refrence as well in doc library to identify that to which infopath form the attachment belongs ?

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the answer to number 5 of [this post](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2010/04/top-10-questions-infopath-file-attachments) for examples of how to do this.

Comment: This is why you give solid answers instead of posting links. Your link is a 404 now.